# Use a Java file that is in a different place than the rest of the project

Tags: java, linux, unix

I have a java source file in my project, that I want to move to an entirely different location than the rest of the files (my unix home dir), but I still want to be able to properly use it in my project. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT - I see there is a vote to close this for being unclear, so - let's say you have a pJava project in Eclispe. All the source files are neatly saved in their relevant packages, under the same directory. Now, I want to move one of the files to somewhere completely different, but still have it used in my project. I hope this clarifies

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that it depends on what your reason is for moving the source file.

1. The Java file is still conceptually part of *this* project, but you're moving it for general organisational purposes.  In which case, the new "completely different" directory is another place where sources should be read from, which most IDEs will call a "source root".  You should configure your project to read sources from there as appropriate for your IDE.
2. You're moving the file because it's distinct from this project.  In which case I would suggest it ought to be a separate project in its own right.  In order to still use the logic in your original project, you'd build the new project into a JAR, and then bring in the JAR as a library dependency (either directly, or using some dependency management system such as Ivy/Maven/etc.).  Again, the details will depend on what your current setup is.

Comment: I'm moving the file because it's a personal configurations file in an otherwise source-controlled project.

Comment: A config file sounds like it usually wouldn't be a _Java source_ file.  They would almost always be text - either [properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html), or XML.  And usually, you'd wire these in by passing the file name as an argument when you *run* the program, rather than having it on the source path for when it's *compiled*.  If this is Java code, I would not say it counts as config.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your Eclipse's `project -> properties -> java build path` , and under the `source` tab click `Link source` then choose the parent folder of your java file .

Comment: The file isn't recognized by the project - do I need to change the package name or something?

Comment: set your java file inside a package folder and don't forget package declaration in the java code.